# jquery: an image over an image does not appear on screen after invoke of the toggle method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a page where A image is over B image. when page is loaded, I get A image hided using the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method. I'd like to re-show this A image over B image on click of a button. but when the button is clicked, this image not appear over B image. I think A image would be under B image. How Can I show A image?

EDIT : sorry for not providing what I've tried: jsfiddle.net/gtchoi/DTcHh/9364/

Comment: Share your code what u have tried....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gtchoi/DTcHh/9364/

Comment: works for jsfiddle but not work for chrome.. that's weird T.T

Comment: A similar question :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271855/toggle-images-on-click-using-jquery

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the toggle() that you have just suggested in your question, I'm going to take my best guess and say you're trying to achieve this using jQuery.

We can achieve your result without using the toggle method:

In your HTML you should have something like this:

`<img src="imagea.jpg" data-pic-src="imageb.jpg" alt="my picture">`

The "data-pic-src" is used for jQuery to understand, however your html doesn't know what this is. It will be used to toggle our image using jQuery.

In your jQuery, you should have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('img').click(function(){

      var temp = $(this).attr('src');   
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-pic-src'));
      $(this).attr('data-pic-src', temp);
    });

});
```

Right here in jQuery, we're just swapping the src value each time it is clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   // hide A image with css propert 'Display' : 'none'. here 

   $("#buttonOver").on('click',function(){

       // hide B image with css propert 'Display' : 'none'. here and set the ( 'z-index' : 'less' / 'opactity' : '0' ).

       // Show A image with css propert 'Display' : 'block'. here (you can make it with 'transition' property as well to show A image ).

   });

});
```

This may help to get what you want.