# How to make a grid of interactive elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

I'm trying to create a portfolio website that resembles [this](http://www.thibaud.be/#), *a full-page grid of images that change when you hover over them*... ([another example, the third screen!](http://blacknegative.com/#!/bullittagency/))

And currently I have a crude solution that looks like:

```
<img src="1.png" id="img" swap="2.png"/>

// then in JS...

$("#img").hover(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    var current = _this.attr("src");
    var swap = _this.attr("swap");
    _this.attr('src',swap).attr('swap',current); 
}); //
```

[code credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271855/toggle-images-on-click-using-jquery)

But this isn't a very scaleable solution and other than having 1000 images, each with their own unique ID which is identified so the src can be toggled, I'm not sure what to do -- **plus I don't know how this would react to different display sizes/screen cut-offs**. And while background-image in CSS tiles nicely, it doesn't allow interactivity... unless maybe you had a JS script track cursor position(?)

!! This is my very first project, any help would be appreciated :) (Codecademy is a very sheltered learning environment........)

Comment: My virtual machine just died a little when I went to 'another example'. Seems like there is too much going on there for my puny 6GB of imaginary RAM. In short `this` would also behave badly on slower devices or those with semi-limited resources.

Comment: What if you did this in CSS, just to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to use ids and create a handler for every image.

this will apply to every image CURRENTLY on the page:

```
$("img").hover(function(){
  var _this = $(this);
  var current = _this.attr("src");
  var swap = _this.attr("swap");
  _this.attr('src',swap).attr('swap',current); 
});
```

and this will react to every image, even images added after the page is loaded:

```
$(document).on('hover', 'img', function () {
  var _this = $(this);
  var current = _this.attr("src");
  var swap = _this.attr("swap");
  _this.attr('src',swap).attr('swap',current); 
});
```

To account for screen sizes and your other concerns, you'd need to either set a fixed width and height on your images, or make sure all your images are of similar resolution.

You could do this with backgrounds as well by creating a grid of divs then change the background of the div on hover, similar to the above handlers.

Comment: Thanks Mark for answering, I actually implemented the first solution and it worked out... Regarding fixed widths/heights, would that be in ems? How would you get them to fill the screen end-to-end, is that just some CSS inherited from HTML? Also... in the first example, the colored squared move around/change position when you zoom in/zoom out, any tips on that? xD thanks!

Comment: since the question is answered, it would be great if you could select my answer as correct!  As to your other questions, there are many solutions out there for each of them.  you can specify widths is px (pixels), em (relative to font size), %.  You could use javascript to provide 'filler' blocks that aren't images to fill out the screen.  You could use media queries to target various screen resolutions.  There are ways to disable zooming.  Lots of answers that i don't have room to detail in a comment.  It's all part of being a web developer.  Lots to learn!